# Changing the Desktop background of the current Space does not change the background for other Space(s)

Tags: macos, desktop

When I change the Desktop background in macOS, the change gets reflected only in the current Space and not the others. The background image I am selecting is one from the default set.

I tried disabling **use different spaces for displays** but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behaviour in macOS. If you have more than one Space, the desktop background is changed only for the current Space and not for the others.

Disabling **use different spaces for displays** have no relation to this behaviour whatsoever.

Comment: So how do I change for the other spaces?

Comment: The Desktop background for each Space is changed individually. Switch to the desired Space, and change the background as you would normally do.